# ASP.NET public object[,] get, set method

Tags: asp.net

How can use Multidimensional Array with get and set?

```
public object[,] icerik
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["icerik"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["icerik"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wouldn't access it just like any other....

```
class someClass{

public object[,] icerik
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["icerik"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["icerik"] = value;
    }
}
}
```

And access:

```
int[,] _array = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 } };

var someclass = new someClass();
someclass.icerk = _array; //Set

_array = someclass.icerk; //read back
```